# ReferenceError: window is not defined in React Native project after adding Supabase call

Tags: react-native, expo, supabase, supabase-js, expo-router

I'm using a React Native project with Expo v49, and I added a Supabase call to read some data from the database, and it works on ios/android,

But when I open the **web** version, I get "ReferenceError: window is not defined", and it shows the error is somewhere in the *expo-router* package

Any help would be appreciated

Tldr: I added the supabase-js call in a useEffect hook of my component (to fetch the backend data), and it works on mobile, but not on React Native Web.